# Django rest framework - adding fields to the existing model field

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework

i want to create a form field to add some input fields and value in particular field in model. I am new to this python and Django rest. Note: i Should not change the model and serializer. i can create new serializer for this.

i am stuck up with this

my expectaion:

```
{
  "id"  : "6fe7c9dd-8d69-4337-8f96-6d67463f6a1d",
  "name": "xyz",
  "age" : 22,
  "additional_detail":{
         "details": {
            "bloodgroup" : "A+ve",
            "city" : "abc"
         }
    }
}
```

models.py

```
class Student(models.model)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntergerField()
    additional_detail = JSONField(_details)
```

serizlizer.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Student
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    queryset = student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

i want to insert into "additional_detail" field like this

```
"details": {
            "bloodgroup" : "A+ve",
            "city" : "abc"
          }
```

i want to insert this fields into new view as a put or patch method by id. 
Is it possible by doing non-model serializer for those addition fileds?
Please send me the complete solution for all .py as files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution could be implement the to_representation method.

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, student):
        # Serialize the student object
        serialized_data = super(StudentSerializer, self).to_representation(student)
        # Include your non-model data
        serialized_data["additional_details"]["details"] = {
            "bloodgroup" : "A+ve",
            "city" : "abc"
        }
        return serialized_data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

Hope it helps!